# Get a page info of Instagram

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

First of all I have found this url to get the public Instagram page info. https://www.instagram.com/facebook/?__a=1. Is this the correct way of accessing info or it can be broken any time in future? I have checked instagram api but I could not find client_credential support(actually I wanna access my Instagram public page from my server). Actually our server need to get and send this info to our native Android and IOS clients. What is the correct way to get page title/image/followers/following/description/posts(including likes and comments count)?

Answer (score 0):

- With out using instagram api,one can get info from instagram's website.Here is demo of getting public profile picture of instagram's user.

---

- I have created api in nodejs to fetch profile picture of instagram's user using cheerio module.And created frontend in angular2.As well as all this component deployed in Heroku Cloud.

---

- [Demo](https://insta-harvester.herokuapp.com/#/insta)

---

- Here is Logic for fetching profile picture of instagram user [Github Repository](https://github.com/golh30/insta-harvester)

Comment: scraping can never be guaranteed and will certainly break the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Any hidden functionality is almost certain to be removed. You should always rely on the public APIs provided.

You should make use of the Instagram Users API, for your particular use case.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Ideal solution is, for every request from your Native Apps, you shouldn't be calling the instagram API, else you may be throttled. You must call instagram API on demand and probably cache the result for an hour or so.

Comment: The problem is that there is no api that allows us get feeds without user interaction

Comment: Since the primary use case is to get the information for your own account, you can generate an accesstoken for yourself and perhaps a refresh token manually and keep refreshing it to access the API.

Comment: You are saying hard-code, access_token and keep refreshing the token using refresh_token?

Comment: If you want to. If you want a cleaner approach, provide a way for your primary user to sign in and save the access token and refresh token in some db.